# I wanted to ask the acceptance of special characters in plaid APIs (first name, last name and address)

Tags: api, special-characters, plaid

Wanted to know if the following characters are included in first name, last name and address fields in Plaid APIs:

- A-Z
- a-z
- Space
- Dot
- Accent Characters
- Hyphen
- Apostrophe-D, L, and O like O'Brien

Can someone please help?

I tried the sandbox APIs and it was working fine. Have I done everything correct and is the production behaviour same?

Answer (score 0):

Plaid returns all name and address strings as they are returned by the financial institution. The Plaid API does not clean up these fields to remove any special characters. Given the large number and diversity of financial institutions supported by the Plaid API, all sorts of special characters could potentially be returned. Consequently, your app should support any and all valid characters in the string field, to the degree that it makes sense for your use case.